# Storing logs in enterprise level in node.js, what data to store on logs?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

Hello all i am going to launch my app on play store now as i am using node.js with mongoDB i am using winston for logging now for production purpose i am only logging errors not the other levels now i was wondering will there be any use of logging http requests and responses i mean i don't know companies store what kind of logs so if anyone have worked in any firm which store logs that would be really helpful for me. Also can anyone pleas tell me can i use winston for logging http request and response or not, i have only heard about morgan for that ??

Comment: we use loggly. you can use kibana to store logs as well. you can use winston to log request/response.

Comment: between logstash/kibana which is better ??

Comment: also please tell me one more thing as i am using winston now should i use morgan or not ??

Comment: kibana visuals data from various sources, including logstash. you use them together.

Comment: use what you're comfortable with.  i use bunyan or winston depending on what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise customers are likely to have compliance requirements for logging and retention.

As a first step, you should confirm your own logging requirements for your app. This question will likely be closed to being too broad or opinion based, but once you know your logging requirements, you can perhaps ask a more specific question.

I recommend using Nginx as a reference proxy, which will provide HTTP access logging for you and also serve your static assets with high performance.

For more advanced logging, consider logging in JSON format instead of plain text, to make it easier to run structured queries against your log. The `bunyan` logging module for Node.js handles that for you.

Enterprise requirements may include logs stored on an additional server.
I don't recommend trying to have your app log over the network directly. If not well done, this could lead to blocking or unbounded memory growth if the network connection with the remote server is down.

Instead, log to STDOUT and let a service like `rsyslog` handle the logging configuration and networking. Logging services were built especially for these needs and do it well. Both `systemd` and `docker` also encourage logging to STDOUT. Here's an example of a syntax that works for a process that is managed by `forever`:

```
  forever start --append -l >(logger --tag your_app_name) ./server.js >/dev/null
```

For a third party logging service, I recommend [Logentries](https://logentries.com/insights/security-compliance/) because it provides detailed notes on their security and compliance features to address your question.

Comment: actually my company is just a startup that's y i didnt know how to handle logging in future when my company will grow also did these Logenties and other stuff are they free or what ??

Comment: actually i am running my app on google cloud so can you tell any service there, also it will be a lot better if it will be free ??